# exclude resource from json object when sending from php to java script

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

**Post edited to clarify the issue, and ask a valid question.**

I have a PHP script to connect to a MySQL db. I have created a PRIVATE.php file that stores the connection string. The script connects and then runs a query on the db returning the results as an associative array. The query does run, and the results are returned.

When I use json_encode to send the results to the java script on the client side, the results are passed to the js. However, what is passed includes the PRIVATE.php reference prior to the associative array. Therefore, it appears that the js can't get to the json object to read the results of the query.

Is there a way to filter out the PRIVATE.php so it doesn't get picked up and sent in the json package? Or is there some way to parse it in the js appropriately?

Here is the PHP:

```
<?php

require './PRIVATE.php';

session_start();

//Connect to MySQL Database
$conn=mysqli_connect($ip,$user,$pass,$db) or die('Error connecting to MySQL 
server: ' . mysqli_error(@conn));

//Some SQL statement returning a result to $myArray    

echo json_encode($myArray);
```

When I debug the js, the variable that is being passed looks like this:

```
myvariable = "PRIVATE.php {"example":"result"}"
```

What I want to see is this:

```
myvariable = {"example":"result"}
```

I have been unable to find an answer that addresses this issue. Any direction would be greatly appreciated. I am sure it is an id10t error on my part, so lay it on me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so the answer here was fairly simple, as I suspected it would be. A little more research into output buffering did the trick.

```
<?php

ob_start();
require './PRIVATE.php';
ob_end_clean();

session_start();

//Connect to MySQL Database
$conn=mysqli_connect($ip,$user,$pass,$db) or die('Error connecting to MySQL server: ' . mysqli_error(@conn));
```

Now the response no longer includes the PRIVATE.php file reference, and the js can access the variable appropriately.

Next, I will move the PRIVATE.php file out of the root directory for additional security. As an added note, the entire connection string can also be included in the PRIVATE.php file. But I don't really see the need to secure it, since the connection variables are already hidden.